# Why won't entity framework allow me to do a .FindBy....()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I create a EDM using my database and saw that while it was able to make relations like

```
Customers.First().Orders
```

there is nothing like

```
Customer.First().Orders.FindOrderByOrderID()

Customer.First().Orders.FindOrderByOrderName()
```

etc.

Maybe I was expecting it to be like that and that's how it doesnt work
and I will probably just have to LINQ to entities and create mangers that handle business logic in them.

or does LINQ to SQL do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ with the `Orders` property, like this:

```
var order = Customer.First().Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == someId);
```

This will return null if there was no matching `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ to Entities you can do this.  Such as the example SLaks posted above.

If you're feeling adventurous, it is possible to write a function to do this.  Since Entity Framework knows which column is the primary key it is possible to write a function like GetEntityByPrimaryKey.

CodeProject has an [article regarding the repository pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx) and if you search for "SelectByKey" you'll see their implementation of that.  I use something similar and find it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you can use LINQ to write more flexible queries. Note, however, that you could probably so something like `FindOrderByOrderName` in .NET 4.0 by creating your own dynamic type (not trivial), that responded to calls following this pattern by building a LINQ query automatically. You'd lose intellisense, of course, and I doubt it would be worth it, but it could be done.

Comment: If I had to do this, I'd probably use a custom T4 template to do this, instead. It's easier, and you get IntelliSense. OTOH, I'd probably not find it worth the effort, since I'd rather just see the LINQ.